# Routing and Remote Access Preventing Hyper-V VM shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2012, rras, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 domain controller with Routing and Remote Access as well as Hyper-V installed.
When I try to shut down a Hyper-V VM, the VM goes into the stopping state and never actually gets out of this state until I restart the Hyper-V host.

It seems that Routing and Remote Access is the cause because when I disable this service from starting up, the VMs will shut down normally. However if the RRAS service had already started and I stop it, the Hyper-V problem still occurs. i.e the RRAS service needs to be disabled when the machine starts.

I have looked at both of the following links but I am unable to find what is causing the problem:

[Hyper-V VMs getting stuck at "Stopping"](https://serverfault.com/questions/459522/hyper-v-vms-getting-stuck-at-stopping)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8f7fa4ad-b479-4e9e-aee6-0b7c6cae6748/windows-2012-and-hyper-v-stuck-at-stopping-why

Is there some special way you are supposed to configure RRAS with Hyper-V? 
Or does anyone have any other suggestions/insights on how to fix this issue?

Comment: So does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround if you have more than one NIC in the machine.

NIC #1 will be left for RRAS.

NIC #2 will only be used for Hyper V. In the Hyper V manager go to Virtual Switch Manager and under External Network make sure you have NIC #2 selected and uncheck "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter."