# Windows 2012R2, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, takes 20 minutes to complete 'stopping' state

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 as a Hyper V client, although I don't often reboot my VMs (I would have to check if other VMs exhibit this behavior), whenever I 'reboot, shutdown, or turn off'. It takes approximately 20+ minutes to complete the process. I am fully up2date including drivers. I've read a few articles, there is a hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2823643 that doesn't appear to apply to my version of Windows Server. I am not quite sure how to diagnose this issue? It's a nuisance when you are doing administrative work and have to wait 60 minutes (in total) for each reboot process to complete.

Regards,

Horace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Remote Access Server installed, that's the problem:

[Routing and Remote Access Preventing Hyper-V VM shutdown](https://serverfault.com/questions/532161/routing-and-remote-access-preventing-hyper-v-vm-shutdown)

Comment: I do and I am going to remove it, I can create a VM, and setup Routing and Remote Access there. I'll get back to you if that solves the issue. Thanks